# How to make PHP return an error in a form in a specific location

Tags: php, html, forms

I am making a user registration system with PHP and html. How can I make it so that if the user enters an invalid username,password,etc it gives the error in red next to the box? At the moment I've been using the die() function, but that just displays a blank page so the user would have to go back. I want the form to stay, with the error in red either at the top of the form, or next to the specific element with the error.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have a look at this site:
http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_form_validation.asp

Or as already stated, have a look at the jQuery validation plugin

Answer (score 0):

you could use the jQuery Validation plugin
http://jqueryvalidation.org/documentation/